# Photo in SwiftUI is not saving

Tags: ios, image, swiftui, camera, photo

I get an error in SwiftUI when I try to save the photo by clicking the button.

It works on the simulator in Xcode and saves the photo but when I try it out on my iPhone this error comes up:

```
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '__SwiftValue<0x102b17690> does not respond to selector selectedImage'
```

Within the button to save the photo I have a snackbar and the UIImageWriteToSavedAlbum which is being called:

```
                                   Button(action: {
                                       withAnimation(.spring())
                                         {
                                             LPSnackbar.showSnack(title: "Photo saved!")
                                             UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewModel.selectedImage!, self, #selector(getter: viewModel.selectedImage), nil)
   }
                                     })
```

The viewModel.selectedImage is from the ViewModel extension as seen below and is called in these places:

```
    @objc @Published var selectedImage: UIImage?

            func didSelectImage(_ image: UIImage?) {
        if ((image) != nil) {
            selectedImage = image
            let imgData = image?.pngData()
            backupImage = UIImage(data: imgData!)

        }
        isPresentingImagePicker = false
    }

            func updateImage(_ image: UIImage?) {
        selectedImage = image
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand why you don't just use the short format of `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewModel.selectedImage!, self, nil, nil)`

Comment: I think the problem is related to the arguments you're passing, read more at [UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(_:_:_:_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/1619125-uiimagewritetosavedphotosalbum)

Comment: You can also check [how to write to the iOS photo album](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/media/uiimagewritetosavedphotosalbum-how-to-write-to-the-ios-photo-album)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I used the short format you mentioned and it works now without returning the error.

Comment: Pleasure is all mine, it looks like the long format is used when you want do something advanced such as error handling, etc